# Devise + Angular + Rails 4 : Changing Logged-in user not validating username/password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

...So close to desired behavior!

Have a Devise / AngularJS / Rails 4 project where the user login/logout is working nearly perfectly. Sending back the X-CSRF-Token and storing the user's email in angular as a cookie so that user hitting refresh doesn't cause angular to lose knowledge of the user.

Only problem I can see is this:  If you are logged in as an admin user then, *WITHOUT logging out*... You just fill in the username/login with some other valid credentials... Devise is authenticating you based on your CSRF token instead of actually validating that username and password.

Therefore, you'll think you are logged in as someone else, but you are actually the previously-logged-in user.  I'm sure this is pretty simple, but just can't seem to nail it... need to force devise/warden to **always check username/password on the CREATE** - don't just be happy with the csrf token.

Here is our sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
  def create
    Rails.logger.debug("(SessionsController.create) ******* ")
    user = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    Rails.logger.debug("(SessionsController.create) back from warden.authenticate ")
    render :status => 200,
      :json => { :success => true,
                 :info => "Logged in",
                 :user => current_user
      }
  end

  def destroy
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_out
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged out",
           }
  end

  def failure
    render :status => 401,
           :json => { :success => false,
                      :info => "Login Credentials Failed"
           }
  end

  def show_current_user
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Current User",
                      :user => current_user

           }
  end
end
```

Here is application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery #with: :exception
  helper_method :require_user, :require_admin

  after_filter :set_csrf_cookie_for_ng

  def set_csrf_cookie_for_ng
    Rails.logger.debug("set_csrf_cookie_for_ng called FAT:#{form_authenticity_token}")
    Rails.logger.debug("protect_against_forgery = #{protect_against_forgery?}")
    cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
  end

  def require_user
    Rails.logger.debug("require_user method in application controller")
    if !user_signed_in?
        flash[:notice] = "Please sign in!"
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  def is_admin_user
    return false if current_user.nil?
    return current_user.admin?
  end

  def is_any_user
    return false if current_user.nil?
    return user_signed_in?
  end

  def verify_admin_user
    unless is_admin_user
      Rails.logger.debug("Unauthorized - Must be Admin")
      respond_to do | format |
        format.json { render :json => [], :status => :unauthorized }
      end
    end
  end

  def verify_any_user
    unless user_signed_in?
      Rails.logger.debug("Unauthorized - Must be Logged-in")
      respond_to do | format |
        format.json { render :json => [], :status => :unauthorized }
      end
    end
  end

  protected

  def verified_request?
    Rails.logger.debug("verified_request called f_a_t:#{form_authenticity_token}. X-XSRF-TOKEN:#{request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN']}")
    super || form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN']
  end
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

Finally, on the Angularjs side, our httpprovider:

```
  .config(["$httpProvider", ($httpProvider) ->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRF-Token"] = $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content")
```

Here is what I see going by in the logs if you were logged-in as an admin, then you attempt to "login-over" as a non admin... Note that "user 1" is the admin who was logged-in already.

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-02 23:21:25 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"nonadmin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"nonadmin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
verified_request called f_a_t:P2FZxg/qwooeNp0Ttme8urXoM9tzWh1bO5y28J8rTHc=. X-XSRF-TOKEN:P2FZxg/qwooeNp0Ttme8urXoM9tzWh1bO5y28J8rTHc=
(SessionsController.create) ******* 
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(SessionsController.create) back from warden.authenticate 
set_csrf_cookie_for_ng called FAT:P2FZxg/qwooeNp0Ttme8urXoM9tzWh1bO5y28J8rTHc=
protect_against_forgery = true
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise/warden (by default) uses a session/cookie based authentication, so its not the CSRF token thats authenticating its the session.

You have a couple of options going forward

1, Disable the login form when angular knows the user is logged in

2, Explicitly sign the user out (by calling `sign_out`) in your create action

3, (**Preferred**) Don't use session authentication over an api. An API should be stateless. By that I mean that the server shouldn't know about whether a user is 'logged in'. You should be sending an authentication token with every request (not relying on the session). Look here http://www.soryy.com/ruby/api/rails/authentication/2014/03/16/apis-with-devise.html for a nice write up.

The basics of token based authentication are:

- Angular sends username and password to server
- Server authenticates username and password, generates a 'token' for that user and sends the token back to angular
- Angular stores that token (in local storage / cookie)
- With each new request (eg: /api/private_thing.json) Angular sends the 'token' (in a header or parameter)
- Server checks that the token belongs to a user record with permission to view the 'private_thing'

Good luck

UPDATE

if you ARE going to go with option 2 then change your create action to:

```
def create 
  sign_out if is_any_user
  render :status => 200, json: { success: true, info: "Logged in", user: current_user }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @BigFive!  Token based authentication is what we usually use with an API.  This project is a "hobby" for a friend and we felt there was tighter coupling with Rails server and the Angular client (also my first Angular project).  That being said, however, you are probably right:  I should treat it as if it WERE a separate API and go with straight-up token authentication.

Comment: No probs mate. Yeah IMHO I think, even if its the same 'app', if your using   rails as an API you should be using tokens. It makes it more scalable too, you could separate the apps later easily enough, or reuse the API for a mobile app later etc.